# Load .txt from remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to get the content of a `.txt` file stored in one of my servers from a javascript which run on another server.

I'm using:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "http://example.com/file.txt",  
    dataType: "jsonp",  
    success: function(data) { remoteFile = data; }  
});
```

But I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at line 1 of the remote `.txt` file.

The text file is something like:

```
----My document----
Once upon a time, there was a fat princess...
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: your file is not json. You have to proxified it server side if it is a cross domain request

Comment: Try changing the dataType to "text". 'file.txt' isn't json.

Comment: @JonLaMarr but then cross domain error will be fired

Comment: @A.Wolff exactly, I need JSONP for cross origin..

Comment: @user2070518 but a text file is not json valid, so, proxify it server side

Comment: I can't, the server where is ran javascript can run only javascript. How can I format my `txt` file to be valid for a JSONP requst?

Comment: Firstly, the server you are trying to grab text file has to allow cross domain request. Is it the case?

Comment: I can allow them, I've complete access to the server where the file is stored.

Comment: If you have complete access to the server, why are you using jsonp instead of CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you wouldn't need to mess around as much if you used [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) [instead of jsonp](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/10/19/using-cors-instead-of-jsonp/).

In PHP it [seems to be](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) as easy as adding something like this on the server side:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Here is one last resource, for [getting CORS working](http://remysharp.com/2011/04/21/getting-cors-working/).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to create a php file that uses curl to get the contents of the file:

```
//getFile.php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['filename'])) {
        $fName = $_GET['filename'];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fName);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $text = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $text;
    }
?>
```

And for the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url : './getFile.php',
    data : { filename : 'http://example.com/file.txt'},
    success : function (r) { console.log(r) //your data }
})
```

Comment: I can use only JS on the receiver server

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not returing a json object, you should change your dataType to text.

```
$.ajax({  
   url: "http://example.com/file.txt",  
   dataType: "text",  
   success: function(data) { remoteFile = data; }  
});
```

Comment: `text` doesn't allow cross origin domain requests

Comment: That's a browser security feature.  No way around that, unfortunately.  You'll either need to change the file to a json file if you want to use json, our you'll need to get the file using a server side script like PHP.

Comment: @user2070518 Yes, if you include it in a php document that also adds the jsonp callback to it.